# Sign JWT with PrivateKey from android Fingerprint API

Tags: android, jwt, digital-signature, android-fingerprint-api

I have some claims and I want to create JWT  and sign it with a PrivateKey created in Fingerprint API.

This is the JWT claim -

```
Header:

{
     "alg": "RS256”,
     “kid”: “ABCDEDFkjsdfjaldfkjg”,
      “auth_type” : “fingerprint” / "pin"
}

Payload:
{
      “client_id”:”XXXXX-YYYYYY-ZZZZZZ”
}
```

Creating KeyPair for fingerprint -

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;

import com.yourmobileid.mobileid.library.common.MIDCommons;

import org.jose4j.base64url.Base64;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.spec.RSAKeyGenParameterSpec;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class BiometricHelper {

    public static final String KEY_NAME = "my_key";
    static KeyPairGenerator mKeyPairGenerator;
    private static String mKid;
    private static KeyStore keyStore;

    public static void init() {
        try {
            mKeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(  KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyPairGenerator", e);
        }
        mKid = MIDCommons.generateRandomString();

         keyStore = null;

        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyStore", e);
        }

        createKeyPair();
    }


    /**
     * Generates an asymmetric key pair in the Android Keystore. Every use of the private key must
     * be authorized by the user authenticating with fingerprint. Public key use is unrestricted.
     */
    public static void createKeyPair() {
        try {

            mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                            KEY_NAME,
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
                            .build());
            mKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return privateKey;
    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicKey() {
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(KEY_NAME).getPublicKey();
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return publicKey;
    }

    public static KeyStore getKeyStore(){
        return keyStore;
    }
    public static String getPublicKeyStr()  {
        StringBuilder publicKey = new StringBuilder("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
        publicKey.append(Base64.encode((getPublicKey().getEncoded())).replace("==",""));
        publicKey.append("\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");


        Log.d("Key==","\n"+publicKey);
        return publicKey.toString();
    }

    public static String getKid() {

        Log.d("mKid==","\n"+mKid);
        return mKid;
    }
 }
```

And creating JWT this way -

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private String createJWT(){

    JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
    claims.setClaim("client_id","”XXXXX-YYYYYY-ZZZZZZ”"); 

    JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();

    jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());
    jws.setKey(BiometricHelper.getPrivateKey());
    jws.setKeyIdHeaderValue(BiometricHelper.getKid());
    jws.setHeader("auth_type","fingerprint");
    jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256);

    String jwt = null;
    try {
        jwt = jws.getCompactSerialization();

    } catch (JoseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("JWT: " + jwt);

    return jwt;
}
```

When i am doing this it am getting -

```
W/System.err: org.jose4j.lang.InvalidKeyException: The given key (algorithm=RSA) is not valid for SHA256withRSA
W/System.err:     at org.jose4j.jws.BaseSignatureAlgorithm.initForSign(BaseSignatureAlgorithm.java:97)
W/System.err:     at org.jose4j.jws.BaseSignatureAlgorithm.sign(BaseSignatureAlgorithm.java:68)
W/System.err:     at org.jose4j.jws.JsonWebSignature.sign(JsonWebSignature.java:101)
```

I tried many other way for signing JWT with PrivateKey so far i did not find solution.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gradle dependency

```
compile group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version: '4.41.1'
```

library I am able to fix the issue and sign JWT using AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey

Here RSASSASigner constructor which takes PrivateKey from Android KeyStore and this signer is used to sign JWSObject.

While looking for solution I did not find much information on this on Web so posting solution here for how to Sign JWT using PrivateKey from android Fingerprint API. Thanks pedrofb for you help :)

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private String createJWT(){
    RSASSASigner signer = new RSASSASigner(BiometricHelper.getPrivateKey());
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    message.put("client_id",mConfiguration.getClientID());

    JWSObject jwsObject = new JWSObject(
            new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.RS256).keyID(BiometricHelper.getKid())
           .customParam("auth_type","touchid").build(),new Payload(message ));
    try {
        jwsObject.sign(signer);
    } catch (JOSEException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String jwt = jwsObject.serialize();

    Log.d("JWT============","\n"+jwt);

    return jwt;
}
```

While working on this thing i came across some bug reported in  Nimbus-JOSE-JWT older version https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/issues/169/android-m-support

Answer (score 1):

You have created a key for encryption only, not for signing. Change

```
mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(
        new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    KEY_NAME,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
                    .build());
```

With

```
mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(
      new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                  KEY_NAME,
                  KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                  .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                  .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
                  .build());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @pedrofb. Yes it makes sense to change KeyProperties. PURPOSE_SIGN from KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT but i am still having issue of 
ClassCastException: android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey cannot be cast to java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey

Comment: Could you post the new stack trace? Have you checked that jose4j is compatible with Android Keystore? Private keys are protected against extraction. If the library is trying to manipulate them it will fail.

Comment: Thanks your comment actually helped me when i did search for jose4j compatible with Android keystore i found out they had know bug, and its been fixed in latest.https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/pull-requests/8/fix-for-android-60-marshmallow/diff

Comment: Well, then, is your problem solved? Do you need any further clarification?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading finding this question and the answers, it's worth mentioning that this key is NOT finger print protected - (`setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` is not set on the key, and `BiometricPrompt` is not being used to approve the signing operation.

To do this correctly with jose4j you need to use it's `jws.prepareSigningPrimitive()` method - https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/176/signing-not-possible-with-an has a discussion and a link to a full example.